# Life of redis connection/pipeline?

Tags: python-2.7, redis

I am creating Redis pipeline as below in python:

```
rPipe = redis.Redis(...).pipeline()
```

Variable **rPipe** is defined in the **__init__** of a class.

The functions in the class execute **set** and **get** commands when called by user using **rpipe**.

```
rpipe.set(...)

rpipe.execute()
```

But as I understand, Redis connections are closed by Redis server automatically, so how long my rPipe will be valid once I created the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal conditions (e.g. unless you're hitting the limit on max number of clients or max buffer size, or if your client sets a specific timeout) Redis doesn't close client connections automatically.

[Pipelines](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) in Redis are a simple way to group commands together and send them to the server all at once, then receiving all the replies in a single step.

Assuming you're using the [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) library (but the same arguments may reasonably hold for any well thought client), (*only*) when you call `execute()` on a pipeline object the commands are packed and sent to Redis. Then the state of the pipeline object is reset and it can be safely reused by the client.

As a side note, if using redis-py, consider that pipelined commands are wrapped in a [MULTI/EXEC transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) by default, which is not always desirable.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. I do need atomic group Transactions. They are critical for my implementation. 

I have a followup question here: Since Redis doesn't close the connections automatically and I assume there is no API for clients to do so, what will happen in case of an Exception? Will redis-py cleanly release the resource?

Since Redis is Single threaded server, will an exception with a query in pipeline be safe?

Comment: Why do you need to manually close connections? Redis-py uses a connections pool, and is able to handle errors even in pipelined commands or in transactions. Please refer to redis-py [readme](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/README.rst) doc and redis [transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) handling for more details. Also the pipeline's [test file](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/tests/test_pipeline.py) contains useful code examples.